# Cross Settings with System.Collections.Generic.ICollection

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, nuget

I'm using a Settings plugin for storing data from James Montemagno, called CrossSettings, for my application, I'm currently trying to assign a setting of type `System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`
but it seems that there is something similar in the plugin for me to attribute this way.

```
public ICollection<UsuarioModel> UsuarioModelSettings
        {
            get
            {
                return AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault(nameof(UsuarioModelSettings), new Guid());
            }
            set
            {
                AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue(nameof(UsuarioModelSettings), value);
            }
        }
```

Here are [all the types](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin/blob/master/src/Plugin.Settings/Platforms/DotNet/Settings.cs) of `GetValueOrDefault` that exist for this plugin.

Would anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save your collection in your device settings you are going to have to serialize your class to do so. For example:

```
public ICollection<UsuarioModel> UsuarioModelSettings
{
    get
    {
         var json = AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault(nameof(UsuarioModelSettings), string.Empty);
         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
             return null;
         return (ICollection<UsuarioModel>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
    }
    set
    {
         var collection = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
         AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue(nameof(UsuarioModelSettings), collection);
    }
}
```

That is `using Newtonsoft.Json;` to serialize your object into a string to save in your settings

Comment: So.. when you `return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);` **gives the error that it is not possible to implicitly convert the type "object" in "System.Collections.Generic.ICollection <Command.Models.UserModel>". Is there an explicit cast (is there a missing cast?)**

Comment: i cast it.. `return (ICollection<UsuarioModel>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);`  I'll test later, but for now your answer is valid. Cheers!

Comment: Yeah, I didn't have your code to try it and I think there is also an override for `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json)`  that you can use if casting doesn't work.

Comment: debugging when i recieve the same property with contains list instanced i get this error. System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid. So how can i pass that correctly?

Comment: If you're getting an invalid cast exception that means you're casting it to an invalid type so something that isn't actually an `ICollection<UsuarioModelSettings>`